# Keep data in HashMap

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I am receiving data with loop using an interface which is giving me JSONObject and "i" from loop. Each time I receive one different:

```
{
    "Id_temp": "1",
    "temperatura": "20",
    "Insertado_temp": "2016-08-16 12:30:29"
}
```

And I need to keep all JsonObjects in one HashMap- But every time I try it, the data from interface overwrite it and then only one Object "the last one" is in Map and other ones get deleted.

I would high appreciate an exemple of how implementing it in my code. Here I write the code. As Key value of HashMap I need the parameter "Id_temp" that is being received in "Id"

```
public class GraficaBarometro extends AppCompatActivity implements OnLoopjCompletedBarometro {

private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

private OnLoopjCompletedBarometro loopjListener;

// Progress Dialog Object
ProgressDialog prgDialog;
// Error Msg TextView Object
TextView errorMsg;
// Email Edit View Object

private String temeperatura;

private Timestamp timestamp;


List<Entry> presiones = new ArrayList<>();
List<Entry> temperaturas = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> dates = new ArrayList<>();


LineChart mChart;

LoopjTasksBarometro loopjTasks;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.actividad_grafica_barometro);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    String idObjeto = (String) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("IdentidadEnviada");

    loopjTasks = new LoopjTasksBarometro(this, this);
    loopjTasks.CaptarParametros(idObjeto);


    mChart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chartbarometro);

    int currentTime = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    timestamp = new Timestamp(currentTime);

    // no description text
    mChart.setDescription("");
    mChart.setNoDataTextDescription("You need to provide data for the chart.");

    // enable touch gestures
    mChart.setTouchEnabled(true);

    mChart.setDragDecelerationFrictionCoef(0.9f);

    // enable scaling and dragging
    mChart.setDragEnabled(true);
    mChart.setScaleEnabled(true);
    mChart.setDrawGridBackground(true);
    mChart.setHighlightPerDragEnabled(true);

    // limit the number of visible entries
    mChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(5);

    // if disabled, scaling can be done on x- and y-axis separately
    mChart.setPinchZoom(true);

    // set an alternative background color
    mChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);


    mChart.animateX(2500);

// to draw X-axis for our graph


    XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setTextSize(11f);
    xAxis.setEnabled(true);
    xAxis.setPosition(com.github.mikephil.charting.components.XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    //xAxis.setAxisMaxValue(125f);
    xAxis.setAxisMinValue(0f);
    xAxis.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true);

    // to draw axis line

    //modify leftYaxis range similarly others
    YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.setTextColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
    leftAxis.setAxisMaxValue(50f);
    leftAxis.setAxisMinValue(10f);
    leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    leftAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);


    YAxis rightAxis = mChart.getAxisRight();
    rightAxis.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    rightAxis.setAxisMaxValue(50f);
    rightAxis.setAxisMinValue(10f);
    rightAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    rightAxis.setDrawZeroLine(false);
    rightAxis.setGranularityEnabled(false);


}


private void agregarToolbar() {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    if (ab != null) {
        // Poner ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â­cono del drawer toggle
        ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.drawer_toggle);
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

}

private void prepararDrawer(NavigationView navigationView) {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                    seleccionarItem(menuItem);
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    return true;
                }
            });

}


private void seleccionarItem(MenuItem itemDrawer) {
    Fragment fragmentoGenerico = null;

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();


    switch (itemDrawer.getItemId()) {
      /*
       case R.id.item_inicio:
            fragmentoGenerico = new FragmentoInicio();
            break;
*/
        case R.id.item_web:

            startActivity(new Intent(this, WebOficial.class));
            break;

        //fragmentoGenerico = new BlankFragment();


        case R.id.item_categorias:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ActividadListaObjeto.class));
            break;

        case R.id.item_acceso:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            break;
    }
    if (fragmentoGenerico != null) {
        fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.contenido_principal, fragmentoGenerico)
                .commit();

        /*
        if(fragmentTransaction) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                    .commit();
           */

    }

    // Setear titulo actual
    setTitle(itemDrawer.getTitle());
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_actividad_principal, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
/*
public String parseHours(long millis){
    String currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm").format(new Date(millis));
    Log.i(UtilitiesGlobal.TAG, "parseHours: " + currentDate);
    return currentDate;
}
*/

private void setData() {
```

linLineDataSet set1, set2;

```
    // create a dataset and give it a type
    //modifications with colour and stuf
    set1 = new LineDataSet(temperaturas, "temperatura");

    set1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    set1.setColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
    set1.setCircleColor(Color.WHITE);
    set1.setLineWidth(2f);
    set1.setCircleRadius(2f);
    set1.setFillAlpha(65);
    set1.setFillColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
    set1.setHighLightColor(Color.rgb(244, 117, 117));
    set1.setDrawCircleHole(false);


    //set1.setFillFormatter(new MyFillFormatter(0f));
    //set1.setDrawHorizontalHighlightIndicator(false);
    //set1.setVisible(false);
    //set1.setCircleHoleColor(Color.WHITE);

    // create a dataset and give it a type
    // similar above
    set2 = new LineDataSet(presiones, "presion");
    set2.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT);
    set2.setColor(Color.RED);
    set2.setCircleColor(Color.WHITE);
    set2.setLineWidth(2f);
    set2.setCircleRadius(2f);
    set2.setFillAlpha(65);
    set2.setFillColor(Color.RED);
    set2.setDrawCircleHole(false);
    set2.setHighLightColor(Color.rgb(244, 117, 117));
    //set2.setFillFormatter(new MyFillFormatter(900f));


    mChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new AxisValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            return dates.get((int) value);
        }

        @Override
        public int getDecimalDigits() {
            return 0;
        }
    });

    ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<ILineDataSet>();
    dataSets.add(set1); // add the datasets
    dataSets.add(set2);


    // create a data object with the datasets
    LineData data = new LineData(dataSets);
    data.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    data.setValueTextSize(9f);

    // set data
    Log.i("Lists Sizedata", temperaturas.size() + " and " + presiones.size());
    mChart.setData(data);
    // move to the latest entry
    mChart.moveViewToX(data.getEntryCount());


}

@Override
public void onLoopjTaskCompletedBarometro(JSONObject parametrosdht11, int i) {


    String temperatura = null;
    String presion = null;
    String fecha = null;
    String Id = null;
    String altitud = null;



    try {

        Id = parametrosdht11.getString("Id_temp");
        temperatura = parametrosdht11.getString("temperatura");
        fecha = parametrosdht11.getString("Insertado_temp");
        presion = parametrosdht11.getString("presion");
        altitud = parametrosdht11.getString("altitud");


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




    temperaturas.add(new Entry(Float.valueOf(i), Float.valueOf(temperatura)));
    presiones.add(new Entry(Float.valueOf(i), Float.valueOf(presion)));
    dates.add(fecha); // reduce the string to just 12:13 etc





    //rrefresh we don't need to refresh since we are setting data after completing task
    mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
    // mChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(12);

    //Log.i(UtilitiesGlobal.TAG, "onSuccess: loopj " + usuarioiJSONbject);
    Log.i(UtilitiesGlobal.TAG, "onSuccess: loopj " + "temperatura: " + temperatura + " presion: "
            + presion + " Fecha Inserción: " + fecha);

}



@Override
public void onLoopCompleteBarometro() {
    setData();
    // it takes time to recieve time. so we set the map after loop is complete okay?
    //mChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(5);
}
```

Now Here is class with hashcode and equals method

```
public class ParametrosBarometro {
int i;
String Id_temperatura;
String temperatura;
String fecha_temperatura;
String presion;
String altitud;


public ParametrosBarometro(String Id_temperatura, String temperatura, String fecha_temperatura, String presion, String altitud) {

    this.Id_temperatura = Id_temperatura;
    this.temperatura = temperatura;
    this.fecha_temperatura = fecha_temperatura;
    this.presion = presion;
    this.altitud = altitud;

}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof ParametrosBarometro) {
        ParametrosBarometro p = (ParametrosBarometro) o;
        return this.Id_temperatura.equals(p.Id_temperatura);
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return this.Id_temperatura.length() * this.Id_temperatura.length();
}
```

}

Comment: You never use `i` in this method. And what is the purpose of this method? You only are assigning local variables.

Comment: And since you are asking about a HashMap, then I think you are reassigning the values for the unique keys and overriding them each time.

Comment: your question is kinda vague (or at least the information provided to understand it). please provide full code which shows you at least tried to get something working.

Comment: I write in 2 minutes full code, I need "i" since later I have send data to chart. Pls check updated code in tow minutes.

Comment: In another class I overwrite method equal and HashCode. Since I have duplicated data, I need a store, this is because I need it.

Comment: *"I write in 2 minutes full code"* No one can write *all* that code shown in question in 2 minutes. No one can type that fast. --- Also, I can't seem to find any declaration of a `HashMap`, or even a `Map`, anywhere in the displayed code. Please read "[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)".

Comment: Dear Friend, I do not uderstand you. I am coding in Android Studio, and now I have to delate duplicates, because my code I have already, I copy and paste here, It is late on the night to waste time making jokes, I wrote a short piece of code because I thought was not need full code, Then Another person asked me full codee and then I copy and paste, and if I am asking help, it is because after checking form several hours exemples I can not catch it. I am learning java since tow month ago. It is hard, this is because I ask help my friend. Thanks for your udertanding.

Comment: I'm totally confused by this question.  You are asking about a `HashMap`, but there are no actual references to "HashMap" in your code.  Or "map".  Or "put".  So what are you actually asking?

Comment: *"I would high appreciate an exemple of how implementing it in my code"* -  Sorry.  No.  That is tantamount to writing your code for you, and that is NOT what this site is for.  Surely you can 1) find an example of how to use hashmaps (written in your native language), 2) understand what it is saying and 3) adapt what it is doing to your problem.

Comment: And if you want a place to look for Java examples, you could the OpenStack Java Documentation site - http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/topics

Comment: Thanks for your smart solution to my case, I am sure it will help a lot to those how are more interested in what "NOT" or what "YES" is stackoverflow than finding a solution.  In the meantime Mr Little Santi leave an elegant solution that give me the way to solve my question and also will help much more to other people with similar question rether than your bla bla bla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am receiving data with loop using an interface which is giving me JSONObject and "i" from loop. [...] As Key value of HashMap I need the parameter "Id_temp" that is being received in "Id".

OK. As simple as this:

```
private final Map<Integer, MyBean> map=new HashMap<Integer, MyBean>();

private void createAndStoreObject(JsonObject json, int i)
    throws ParseException
{
    SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    MyBean myBean=new MyBean(json.getInt("Id_temp"), json.getInt("temperatura"), format.parse(json.getString("Insertado_temp")));
    this.map.put(myBean.getId(), myBean);
}

class MyBean
{
    private final int id;

    private final int temperature;

    private final Date insertionDate;

    public MyBean(int id, int temperature, Date insertionDate)
    {
        super();
        this.id=id;
        this.temperature=temperature;
        this.insertionDate=insertionDate;
    }

    public int getId()
    {
        return this.id;
    }

    // ... getters ...
}
```

As you can see, being the key an Integer (which is a class bundled with the Java Runtime Environment), there is no need to override the `hashCode` nor `equals` methods (Integer has them already).